# Matlab code gen build issue & differences between processes on WIN10 and WIN2016 Server Docker Container

Tags: docker, matlab, cmake, build, visual-studio-2015

I have a Matlab code generation process running on a WIN10 Computer and a WIN2016 Server Docker Container with Desktop Experience. (mcr.microsoft.com/windows:1809).

Both have as dependencies: Linaro, CMake, Ninja, Visual Studio 2015 Build Tools.

Both are self-hosted windows agent and use Azure Devops CI/CD Pipeline as a intermediary.

My Goal is replicating and transferring the behavior I see on my working CI/CD Pipeline workflow that uses my win10 self hosted agent to my docker container. Hence I need similar or equivalent output from the Matlab Process job steps.

But at the moment, my Matlab build process isn't picking up all my dependencies during it's build operation & causing bugs.(ex: I'm not seeing a toolchain call)
**Notes, as part of the build hierarchy Coo is a giant simulation reference model that contains Boo, who also contains Foo.

**WIN10 CI/CD LOG - Matlab Build Step**

```
2020-12-03T18:27:48.7933494Z ### Writing header file Foo.h
2020-12-03T18:27:48.7934118Z .
2020-12-03T18:27:48.7934303Z ### Writing source file Foo.cpp
2020-12-03T18:27:48.7934765Z ### Writing source file C:\agentS\_work\1\s\Foo_MBD\CodeGeneration\genCode\slprj\ert\_sharedutils\rt_modd.cpp
2020-12-03T18:27:48.7935075Z ### Writing header file C:\agentS\_work\1\s\Foo_MBD\CodeGeneration\genCode\slprj\ert\_sharedutils\rt_modd.h
2020-12-03T18:27:48.7935299Z ### TLC code generation complete.
2020-12-03T18:27:49.8420364Z .### Using toolchain: Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 v14.0 | nmake (64-bit Windows)
2020-12-03T18:27:50.4226563Z ### Creating 'C:\agentS\_work\1\s\Foo_MBD\CodeGeneration\genCode\slprj\ert\FooFolder\Foo.mk' ...
2020-12-03T18:27:50.4760812Z ### Successful completion of code generation for model: Foo
2020-12-03T18:27:51.0216181Z ### Checking the status of model reference RTW target for model 'Boo' used in 'BooDepency'
2020-12-03T18:27:51.0274892Z ### Model reference RTW target (Boo.cpp) for model Boo is out of date because Boo.cpp does not exist.
2020-12-03T18:27:51.4500966Z ### Starting build procedure for model: Boo
2020-12-03T18:27:51.6342552Z ### Generating code and artifacts to 'Model specific' folder structure
2020-12-03T18:27:51.6346384Z ### Generating code into build folder: C:\agentS\_work\1\s\Foo_MBD\CodeGeneration\genCode\slprj\ert\Boo
2020-12-03T18:27:55.7613326Z ### Invoking Target Language Compiler on Boo.rtw
2020-12-03T18:27:55.7634508Z ### Using System Target File: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017b2\rtw\c\ert\ert.tlc
2020-12-03T18:27:57.2316454Z ### Loading TLC function libraries
```

**WIN2016 SERVER CI/CD LOG - Matlab Build Step**

```
2021-01-08T17:17:13.5588372Z ### Writing header file Foo.h
2021-01-08T17:17:13.5588483Z .
2021-01-08T17:17:13.5588598Z ### Writing source file Foo.cpp
2021-01-08T17:17:13.5588892Z ### Writing source file C:\azp\agent\_work\1\s\Foo_MBD\CodeGeneration\genCode\slprj\ert\_sharedutils\rt_modd.cpp
2021-01-08T17:17:13.5591172Z ### Writing header file C:\azp\agent\_work\1\s\Foo_MBD\CodeGeneration\genCode\slprj\ert\_sharedutils\rt_modd.h
2021-01-08T17:17:13.5593186Z ### TLC code generation complete.
2021-01-08T17:17:21.0428004Z .### Successful completion of code generation for model: Foo
2021-01-08T17:17:25.0400492Z ### Checking the status of model reference RTW target for model 'Boo' used in 'BooDepency'
2021-01-08T17:17:25.0989857Z ### Model reference RTW target (Boo.cpp) for model Boo is out of date because Boo.cpp does not exist.
2021-01-08T17:17:25.7978600Z ### Starting build procedure for model: Boo
2021-01-08T17:17:26.8324115Z ### Generating code and artifacts to 'Model specific' folder structure
2021-01-08T17:17:26.8419696Z ### Generating code into build folder: C:\azp\agent\_work\1\s\Foo_MBD\CodeGeneration\genCode\slprj\ert\Boo
2021-01-08T17:17:42.5806329Z ### Invoking Target Language Compiler on Boo.rtw
2021-01-08T17:17:42.6248549Z ### Using System Target File: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017b\rtw\c\ert\ert.tlc
2021-01-08T17:17:47.8626194Z ### Loading TLC function libraries
```

**Error:**

```
2021-01-08T17:44:26.8831417Z CGIR assertion 'Allocation failed. Insufficient memory to continue.' failed in 'b:\matlab\src\cg_ir\util_prim\releasemempool.hpp:100'
2021-01-08T17:44:26.8838372Z [  0] 0x00000000f792269d                                bin\win64\rtwcg.dll+02631325
2021-01-08T17:44:26.8838625Z [  1] 0x00000000f79226b9                                bin\win64\rtwcg.dll+02631353
2021-01-08T17:44:26.8838890Z [  2] 0x00000000f792269d                                bin\win64\rtwcg.dll+02631325
2021-01-08T17:44:26.8839131Z [  3] 0x00000000f79226b9                                bin\win64\rtwcg.dll+02631353
2021-01-08T17:44:26.8839423Z [  4] 0x00000000f79226b9                                bin\win64\rtwcg.dll+02631353
2021-01-08T17:44:26.8850385Z [  5] 0x00000000f79226b9                                bin\win64\rtwcg.dll+02631353
2021-01-08T17:44:26.8850920Z [  6] 0x00000000f79226b9                                bin\win64\rtwcg.dll+02631353
2021-01-08T17:44:26.8851176Z [  7] 0x00000000f79226b9                                bin\win64\rtwcg.dll+02631353
2021-01-08T17:44:26.8851566Z [  8] 0x00000000f79226b9                                bin\win64\rtwcg.dll+02631353
2021-01-08T17:44:26.8851820Z [  9] 0x00000000f79226b9                                bin\win64\rtwcg.dll+02631353
2021-01-08T17:44:26.8852057Z [ 10] 0x00000000f792269d                                bin\win64\rtwcg.dll+02631325
2021-01-08T17:44:26.8852290Z [ 11] 0x00000000f79226b9                                bin\win64\rtwcg.dll+02631353
2021-01-08T17:44:26.8857614Z [ 12] 0x00000000f79226b9                                bin\win64\rtwcg.dll+02631353
2021-01-08T17:44:26.8857847Z [ 13] 0x00000000f792269d                                bin\win64\rtwcg.dll+02631325
2021-01-08T17:44:26.8858087Z [ 14] 0x00000000f79226b9                                bin\win64\rtwcg.dll+02631353
2021-01-08T17:44:26.8860899Z [ 15] 0x00000000f792269d                                bin\win64\rtwcg.dll+02631325
2021-01-08T17:46:34.3864280Z ### Build procedure for model: 'Coo' aborted due to an error.
2021-01-08T17:46:51.2150096Z Error using tlc_c (line 176)
2021-01-08T17:46:51.2153547Z Unexpected or internal error encountered in "in CGIR: b:\matlab\src\cg_ir\util_prim\releasemempool.hpp line 100: Allocation failed. Insufficient memory to continue.
2021-01-08T17:46:51.2153868Z ".  Please report this to MathWorks if you can cause it to recur
2021-01-08T17:46:51.2157314Z 
2021-01-08T17:46:51.2157502Z Error in coder.internal.ModelBuilder/buildProcedure (line 710)
2021-01-08T17:46:51.2159775Z                 buildResult = tlc_c(h,...
2021-01-08T17:46:51.2159884Z 
2021-01-08T17:46:51.2165597Z Error in coder.internal.ModelBuilder/make_rtw (line 197)
2021-01-08T17:46:51.2165818Z                 buildResult = buildProcedure...
2021-01-08T17:46:51.2165917Z 
2021-01-08T17:46:51.2168320Z Error in coder.internal.ModelCodegenMgr/make_rtw (line 8)
2021-01-08T17:46:51.2171494Z     buildResult = obj.make_rtw(varargin);
2021-01-08T17:46:51.2171616Z 
2021-01-08T17:46:51.2171708Z Error in make_rtw (line 20)
2021-01-08T17:46:51.2171859Z buildResult = h.make_rtw(buildArgs, varargin{:});
```

Any Hints?

I'm not sure if it's a problem with my dependencies? Or an issue with memory in my docker container? Or something else?

**Extra info :**

I use chocolatey as a packet manager in my docker files to install my dependencies. They are all on the PATH, but may be in different location than my work computer. I didn't make the Cmake files or the core matlab project structure, so I'm not sure if the build process is absolute path dependent.

**Update:**

I tried running mex -v setup on both host and Dockers container.
I have this on host :

```
...
Found installed compiler 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 (C)'.
...
Found installed compiler 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 (C)'.
```

I didn't find any configured compiler on Docker Container

```
... Looking for file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\amd64\cl.exe' ...Yes.
... Looking for folder 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC' ...Yes.
...
Did not find installed compiler 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 (C)'.
...
Did not find installed compiler 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 (C)'.
```

Could that cause the issue? How do I remedy that?

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

Add a new registry entry via the Docker file.

```
RUN reg add  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7 /v 14.0 /t REG_SZ /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\"
```

**Note:**

I opened another question related to a sub-question of this issue.
I got my answer.
Turns out that sub-problem solution applied to the whole bug discussed here.

[Chocolatey generated VS 2015 Compiler not found on docker image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65635999/chocolatey-generated-vs-2015-compiler-not-found-on-docker-image/65672942#65672942)