# Chocolatey generated VS 2015 Compiler not found on docker image

Tags: windows, visual-studio, docker, matlab, chocolatey

I tried to install visual studio 2015 build tools on a Docker Container using the chocolatey packet manager. I need it for a Matlab code gen build operation.
The chocolatey steps works fine.
But my docker container can't find the compiler.
Any Hints?

**Docker**

```
RUN powershell -command choco install -y vcredist140
RUN powershell -command choco install -y vcbuildtools -ia "/Full"
```

Using `mex -v -setup`
I have:

**Host(WIN10):**

```
... Looking for compiler 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 (C)' ...
... Looking for registry setting 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VC7' 14.0 ...No.
... Looking for registry setting 'HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VC7' 14.0 ...No.
... Looking for registry setting 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VC7' 14.0 ...Yes ('C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\').
... Looking for file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\amd64\cl.exe' ...Yes.
... Looking for folder 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC' ...Yes.
... Looking for registry setting 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1' InstallationFolder ...No.
... Looking for registry setting 'HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1' InstallationFolder ...No.
... Looking for registry setting 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1' InstallationFolder ...Yes ('C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\').
... Looking for registry setting 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7' 14.0 ...No.
... Looking for registry setting 'HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7' 14.0 ...No.
... Looking for registry setting 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7' 14.0 ...Yes ('C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\').
... Looking for registry setting 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VC7' 14.0 ...No.
... Looking for registry setting 'HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VC7' 14.0 ...No.
... Looking for registry setting 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VC7' 14.0 ...Yes ('C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\').
... Looking for registry setting 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VC7' 14.0 ...No.
... Looking for registry setting 'HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VC7' 14.0 ...No.
... Looking for registry setting 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VC7' 14.0 ...Yes ('C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\').
... Looking for file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat' ...Yes.
... Looking for folder 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC' ...Yes.
... Looking for registry setting 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows Kits\Installed Roots' KitsRoot10 ...Yes ('C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\').
... Looking for registry setting 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows Kits\Installed Roots' KitsRoot10 ...Yes ('C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\').
... Executing command 'echo off&set "sdkversion="&(for /f %a IN ('dir "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\" /b /ad-h /on') do ( @if exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\%a\ucrt\" set "sdkversion=%a" ))&call echo %sdkversion%' ...Yes ('10.0.17763.0').
Found installed compiler 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 (C)'.
```

**Docker(WINSERV2016):**

```
... Looking for file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\amd64\cl.exe' ...Yes.
... Looking for folder 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC' ...Yes.
... Looking for registry setting 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1' InstallationFolder ...No.
... Looking for registry setting 'HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1' InstallationFolder ...No.
... Looking for registry setting 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1' InstallationFolder ...Yes ('C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\').
... Looking for registry setting 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7' 14.0 ...No.
... Looking for registry setting 'HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7' 14.0 ...No.
... Looking for registry setting 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7' 14.0 ...No.
... Looking for registry setting 'HKCU\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7' 14.0 ...No.
... Looking for registry setting 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7' 15.0 ...No.
... Looking for registry setting 'HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7' 15.0 ...No.
... Looking for registry setting 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7' 15.0 ...No.
... Looking for registry setting 'HKCU\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7' 15.0 ...No.
Did not find installed compiler 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 (C)'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some exploration, I found that:

1. mex -v -setup lookup table is in   `C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017b\bin\win64\mexopts\msvcpp2015.xml`
2. Matlab needs specifics VS7 registry values to say that a VS 2015 compiler is installed.
3. Chocolatey only Install VC7 registry values.

If you add this to a docker file or run line in CLI container:

```
RUN reg add  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7 /v 14.0 /t REG_SZ /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\"
```

It fixes the issue.

msvcpp2015.xml

```
        <VSINSTALLDIR>
            <or>
                <hklmExists path="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7" name="14.0" />
                <hkcuExists path="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7" name="14.0" />
                <hklmExists path="SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7" name="14.0" />
                <hkcuExists path="SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7" name="14.0" />
                <hklmExists path="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7" name="15.0" />
                <hkcuExists path="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7" name="15.0" />
                <hklmExists path="SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7" name="15.0" />
                <hkcuExists path="SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7" name="15.0" />
            </or>
        </VSINSTALLDIR>
```

Ref:
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/412396-how-to-setup-matlab-compiler-to-use-msvc2017-build-tools